# Trying to understand "sync" in Go. Why does this work?

Tags: go

"This program should go to 11, but sometimes it only prints 1 to 10. Fix the code and explain why." is the task.
I'm trying to understand why this code works. If it's just that i'm adding "assembler code" to the compiler so Print manages to print the last 11.

So my question is: Why does this code manage to print the last 11 when im adding  wg.Wait() **after** close? Im my head, I want to add wg.Wait() before close(ch) so that the channel doesn't close before we are done, but that gives us a deadlock as we would wait forever to receive more values from the channel.

thanks

Original code had no code related to "sync".

```
func main() {

    ch := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup // added code

    wg.Add(1) // added code
    go Print(ch, &wg) // added code (&wg)

    for i := 1; i <= 11; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }

    close(ch)
    wg.Wait() // added code

}

// Print prints all numbers sent on the channel.
// The function returns when the channel is closed.
func Print(ch <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) { // added code (wg *sync.WaitGroup)
    for n := range ch { // reads from channel until it's closed
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
    wg.Done() // added code
}
```

Comment: Where did you add "assembler code" here?

Comment: I haven't added assembler code. The problem from the beginning arises because when the code is compiled, we can't know how the code is put together i machine code. What I meant, with a little sarcasm, was that I want to understand why my implementation with "sync" works in theory. It might, but I don't think so, just be that the extra code adds extra lines of machine code so the main goroutine takes longer time than from the beginning. And so Print manage to print the last number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `wg.Wait`, the main goroutine may terminate before the second goroutine can finish printing.

You are using a channel without a buffer, so whenever the main goroutine sends a value through the channel, the goroutine receives the value. However, this does not guarantee that the value is printed. The main goroutine can start expecting before print completes and can terminate the program. The waitgroup is necessary to make sure main goroutine waits until the printing goroutine completes.

Comment: Yes, I follow the reasoning this far. I understand why I want to use Wait and why I want it to be in the main goroutine. The question is why Close(ch) doesn't close the channel, and so finishes the printing goroutine, when placed where it is placed.

Like you say, "The waitgroup is necessary to make sure main goroutine waits until the printing goroutine completes", but Close() is what makes the printing goroutine finish. In my head, Close() closes the channel, making the printing goroutine return, and so its done and main goroutine terminates. But can we know all i has been printed?

Comment: A write to an unbuffered channel blocks until there is a read. Closing a channel doesn't.  After closing the channel main goroutine does not wait for the other goroutine to detect that.

Comment: Ok! That is answer to my question. Thanks a lot